# Variable variable Timing Out In An IF Statement In PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to set some dynamic variables to NULL to avoid the "Warning: Undefined variable" warning. I am using this piece of code:

```
        $i = 1;
        while($i <= 15){
            if(!isset(${"ss".$i})){
            ${"ss".$i} = null;
            $i = $i + 1;
            }
        }
```

However, it just times out at 60 seconds
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /www/sites/164/edit.php on line 94

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You only increase $i inside the IF statement. If the IF is false, it'll be trapped in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to suppress the warnings instead of having to run that loop every time.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting in  infinite loop. Change your code to:

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 15) {
   if(!isset(${"ss".$i})){
      ${"ss".$i} = null;
   }
   $i = $i + 1;
}
```